# Log Console Output

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, logs, console, terminal-emulator

Is there a way to not only protocol/log the console inputs (like the history), but also the console output by default (without the constant usage of pipes)?

Comment: @JdeBP - I don't see a persistent or default way to do that here.

Comment: @Christopher - Ubuntu is mentioned in the tags

Comment: @Christopher - not really. Is there some kind of tutorial?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Terminator](https://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html). Enable the Logger plugin in its preferences, then right click on the terminal and select "Start Logger"

Comment: Is there a way to have it done with any used terminal?

Comment: Check the answers in the duplicate of link for other solutions. ttyrec looks interesting too